# the order of functions js

Tags: javascript, dom

I'd like to create an HTML element and then drag it across the screen.

So the code consists of a function where the element movement is defined. The function works on an element created within the HTML body tags. I can click on the header and drag the div wherever I want.
As a next instance, I created a button, to add a new div item. I commented out the HTML div element within the body tags. The js item appears no problem on button click and the applied styles are correct.
The problem is when I'm trying to use both functions together. I am getting within the console
'Cannot set property 'onmousedown' of null
at dragElement'
I thought that if the div item is created before the function is executed there will be no problem running this, but it still throws an error.

I tried to invoke the function newHTMLitem() within the dragElement() function but it does not seem to help. On the other hand if the newHTMLitem() is invoked at the end of the script the HTML item does not appear at all.

Any ideas?

```
document.getElementById('addItem').addEventListener('click',function newHTMLitem(){
  
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('mydiv');
  let header = document.createElement('div');
  header.classList.add('mydivheader');
  let body = document.createElement('p');

  div.appendChild(header);
  div.appendChild(body);

  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
);

//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.querySelector(".mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {


  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.querySelector(".mydivheader")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.querySelector(".mydivheader").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple errors,

```
e.target.style.top = (e.target.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
e.target.style.left = (e.target.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
```

You had `elmt.style.top` - which was a typo, but also a misunderstanding. In event listeners the element your listening to is the `event.target`

Also you needed to attach your event listener to your newly created element. Which also meant you had to move 3 functions up to the top since they're used by the listeners. I added

```
  div.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
```

```js
function dragMouseDown(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  e.preventDefault();
  // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
  pos3 = e.clientX;
  pos4 = e.clientY;
  document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
  // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
  document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
}

function elementDrag(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  e.preventDefault();
  // calculate the new cursor position:
  pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
  pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
  pos3 = e.clientX;
  pos4 = e.clientY;
  // set the element's new position:
  e.target.style.top = (e.target.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
  e.target.style.left = (e.target.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";

}

function closeDragElement() {
  /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
  document.onmouseup = null;
  document.onmousemove = null;
}

document.getElementById('addItem').addEventListener('click', function newHTMLitem() {

  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('mydiv');
  let header = document.createElement('div');
  header.classList.add('mydivheader');
  let body = document.createElement('p');

  div.appendChild(header);
  div.appendChild(body);

  document.body.appendChild(div);
  div.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
});

//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.querySelector(".mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;
  if (document.querySelector(".mydivheader")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.querySelector(".mydivheader").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }


}
```

```css
.mydivheader {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

#addItem {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydivheader">Header</div>
<button id='addItem'>Add item</button>
```

Comment: Brilliant :) thanks a mill for the answer and an explanation :)

Comment: You’re welcome, I’d it helped you solve you question please mark it as the answer